# coffeescript on click removes class

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have a navbar with links structured this way `.nav li a`

This code adds "active" to "li" when I click "a".
But it removes it right away.

```
jQuery ->
      $('.nav a').on 'click', -> 
                $(this).parent().addClass('active')
```

How to keep "active" on selected "li"?

ps this is what I have on jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav a").on("click", function () {
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Comment: [Your JQuery seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/z2x0eegj/).

Comment: @Vucko yes it is, but I want to have it written with coffeescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `coffescript` from `JS`, check out [js2coffee.org](http://js2coffee.org/).

If you enter your script in it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav a").on("click", function () {
        $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
});
```

You'll get:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".nav span").on "click", ->
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass "active"
    $(this).parent().addClass "active"
    return

  return
```

Just watch for **indentation** as coffescripts uses it.

Comment: Thanks for the site. But same problem here. It adds "active" class to "li" but it disappear after click.  It's like add active and remove it right away.

Comment: Oh, I've just found the problem was with rails turbolinks. It works. Thanks :)